# Regex for matching specified text, then anything except a specified text, then anything, then specified text

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-negation

I've done a ton of searching but I think it's just over my head. I can't figure out what I should be doing to parse this text.

Lets say I have the strings:
case 1: "hi! hello, how are you doing today"
case 2: "hi! hello, how are you today"
case 3: "hi! hello, doing you today"
case 4: "hi! hello, how are you doing today blah"

If I wanted to match where theres any text, then "hello" then any text (but not ", doing" and ends with "today", how would that be done?

On http://www.regexpal.com/ I'm using `(hello)((?!, doing).*)` which will not select case 3, but will select case 2 and 4, when I want it to only select case 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: You say you want to select just #1? Not #1 and #2? See [this regex demo](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97991).

Comment: Your regex matches all 4 cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You helped me out a ton!!!!! Thank you so, so, much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*?hello(?:(?!,\s+doing).)*today$
```

See the [regex demo](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97991)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `hello` - a literal substring
- `(?:(?!,\s+doing).)*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, that do not start a sequence defined as:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `doing` - a literal substring
- `today` - a literal substring
- `$` - end of string.